# PyGame: Char not moving

Tags: python, pygame

I have written a code which aims to move a horse when pressing the right arrow key, but when I press it, it doesnt move. I can't seem notice where the problem is. I have typed `print(a.locx)` in `def char()` to see `a.locx` is increasing or not but its not and also in `class Horse()`'s method `def location()` when I press right arrow key `self.locx` is increasing and then instantly decreasing.

```
import pygame
from pygame import locals
def main():
    global window,width,height
    pygame.init()
    width ,height = 500,500
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

    while True:
        window.fill((0,0,0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if pygame.event == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        char()

        pygame.display.update()


def char():
    a = Horse()
    window.blit(a.horse1,(a.locx,a.locy))
    print(a.locx)
    a.location()

class Horse():
    def __init__(self):
        self.horse1 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/pygeym/blitz/Horse_Walk3.png")

        self.horse2 = []

        for horse in range(0,8):
            self.horse2.append(pygame.image.load(("C:/Users/niimet/Desktop/pygeym/blitz/Horse_Walk{}.png").format(horse+1)))

        self.horse3 = []

        for horse in self.horse2:
            self.horse3.append(pygame.transform.flip(horse,True,False))

        self.locx = 0
        self.locy = width - self.horse1.get_size()[1]

    def location(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            print(self.locx,"1")
            self.locx += 200
            print(self.locx,"2")

main()
```

Comment: Just curious, what compiler are you using?

Comment: did you mean ide?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, IDE

Comment: pycharm why you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you crate a new `Horse` object in every frame and so the horse continuously "starts" at its initial position.

> ```py
> def char():
>    a = Horse() # <--- creates new Hors object with "self.locx = 0"
>    # [...]
> ```

Create a `Horse` in global name space and use this object:

```py
def main():
    global window, width, height, a

    pygame.init()
    width, height = 500,500
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    a = Horse()

    while True:
        window.fill((0,0,0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if pygame.event == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        char()

        pygame.display.update()

def char():
    window.blit(a.horse1,(a.locx,a.locy))
    print(a.locx)
    a.location()
```

Comment: Yes this is it how i coulndt notice that :D